# The restriction of unit norm functionals to the ball are a closed subset of functionals defined over a ball

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm reading a proof of the following claim. The proof contains some claims I am not following, can someone elaborate?

> *Claim:*
>
> Denote the closed unit balls in $X$ and $X^*$ by $B$ and $B^*$, respectively. Denote $\mathcal{F}(B)$ to be a set of functions of the form $f:B \rightarrow [-1,1]$ with pointwise product topology (for basis, see below). Define the restriction map $R: B^* \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(B)$ by $R(\phi) = \phi|_B$ for $\phi \in B^*$. Show $R(B^*)$ is a closed subset of $\mathcal{F}(B)$.
>
> *Proof:*
>
> Let $f: B \rightarrow [-1,1]$ be a point of closure with respect to the pointwise product topology of $R(B^*)$ (defn of topology given below). To show $f \in R(B^*)$ it suffices to show that for all $u, v \in B$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $u + v$ and $\lambda u$ also belong to $B$,
> $$f(u+v)= f(u)+f(v) \text{ and } f(\lambda u)= \lambda f(u)$$
> However, for any $\epsilon > 0$, the weak-* neighborhood of $f$, $\mathcal{N}_{\epsilon, u,v,u+v}(f)$ (see below for definition, this is an element of the basis of weak-* topology), contains some $R(\phi_\epsilon)$ and since $\phi_{\epsilon}$ is linear, we have $|f(u + v) - f (u) - f (v)| < 3\epsilon$. Therefore, $f(u+v)= f(u)+f(v)$ holds. The proof of $f(\lambda u)= \lambda f(u)$ is similar.

---

> In the proof above, we denote a basis element of the weak-* topology as: $$\mathcal{N}_{\epsilon,x_1,...x_n}(\psi) =\bigg \{\psi' \in B^* \, \bigg| \, |\psi'(x_i)-\psi(x_i) | < \epsilon \quad \forall i = 1,...n\bigg\} \\ =\bigg \{\psi' \in \mathcal{F}(B) \, \bigg| \, |\psi'(x_i)-\psi(x_i) | < \epsilon \quad \forall i = 1,...n\bigg\}$$
> The pointwise product topology (the basis shown in the second equality) and weak-* topology are homeomorphic (there's a bijection between basis elements established by the equality above).

Questions:

1. *"To show $f \in R(B^*)$ it suffices to show..."* -- What are they verifying about $f$ here? Loosely, my understanding is that proofs of closure proceed as follows: suppose $x \in \overline{X}$, check neighborhoods of $x$. In particular, we suppose $x$ exists, there are no "properties" of $x$ to check.
2. "*for any $\epsilon > 0$, the weak-$^*$ neighborhood of $f$, $\mathcal{N}_{\epsilon, u,v,u+v}(f)$ ... contains some $R(\phi_\epsilon)$*" -- What is $\phi_{\epsilon}$? Why does there exist $R(\phi_\epsilon) \in \mathcal{N}_{\epsilon, u,v,u+v}(f)$? This is where they are establishing that the $f$ they chose is a limit point, right?
3. "*However...* [to the end]" -- What's being verified here? Aren't we done after we show every neighborhood contains a point of the set? (i.e. after step 2).

Comment: Can you please state the source of the proof you're quoting?

Comment: This is Royden, Chap 15 Section 1. It's part of the proof he writes for Alaoglu's Theorem (thm un-numbered). (I looked for the link in google books, but one cannot search it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As stated, they are verifying that $f(u+v) = f(u)+f(v)$ and $f(\lambda u) = \lambda f(u)$.  That's all.

   Why does this imply $f \in R(B^*)$?  You have to show that there exists $\phi \in B^*$ such that $f = \phi|_B$.  There is a natural candidate for $\phi$: since $\phi$ is supposed to be linear, it should be determined by its values on the unit sphere, where it is supposed to agree with $f$.  So let $\phi(x) = \|x\| f(\frac{x}{\|x\|})$ with $\phi(0)=0$.  Given what's been shown about $f$, it should now be a straightforward exercise to show:

   - $f(x) = \phi(x)$ for $x \in B$, i.e. $f = \phi|_B$
   - $\phi$ is linear, i.e. for any $x,y \in X$ and any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$ and $\phi(\lambda x) =\lambda \phi(x)$
   - $\|\phi\| \le 1$, i.e. for every $x \in B$ we have $|\phi(x)| \le 1$.  (This follows immediately from the fact that $f = \phi|_B$.

   And the latter two statements are exactly the definition of $\phi \in B^*$.
2. By assumption, $f$ is in the closure of $R(B^*)$.  Since $\mathcal{N}_{\epsilon, u,v,u+v}$ is a (weak-*) neighborhood of $f$, it must therefore contain some element of $R(B^*)$; call it $g$.  But saying $g \in R(B^*)$ means there exists some element of $B^*$, call it $\phi_\epsilon$, such that $g = R(\phi_\epsilon)$.  That is to say, there exists $\phi_\epsilon$ such that $R(\phi_\epsilon) \in \mathcal{N}_{\epsilon, u,v,u+v}$.  Their wording "$\mathcal{N}$ contains some $R(\phi_\epsilon)$" is just a more abbreviated way to say it.
3. The paragraph starting with "However..." is where they actually verify that $f(u+v) = f(u)+f(v)$ and $f(\lambda u) = \lambda f(u)$.

Comment: Thanks! okay, at a high level then: To show $R(B^*)$ is a closed subset of $\mathcal{F}(B)$, they suppose $f$ is in the closure of $R(B^*)$. Then they have to show that there's an element of $B^*$ that maps to it. How does this show $R(B^*)$ is a closed subset of $\mathcal{F}(B)$?

Comment: @yoshi: It shows that every element of the closure of $R(B^*)$ is actually in $R(B^*)$.  In other words, $\overline{R(B^*)} \subseteq R(B^*)$.  Since the reverse containment is trivial, this shows $R(B^*)$ is equal to its own closure and therefore is closed.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing that we showed that every element is in the closure. The next comment contains my (probably incorrect) reasoning.

Comment: $R: B^* \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(B)$ will take $\|x\|f(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) \mapsto f(x)$ when $f \in \overline{R(B^*)}$. But why is $\|x\|f(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) \in R(B^*)$? Computing we get: $\|x\|f(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) = f(\|x\|\frac{x}{\|x\|})=f(x)$ which we supposed was in $\overline{R(B^*)}$ not $R(B^*)$

Comment: @yoshi: We select an arbitrary element $f$ of $\overline{R(B^*)}$, and try to show that it's in $R(B^*)$.  Please reread what I wrote in #1. To do this, we begin by verifying the linearity properties $f(u+v) = f(u)+f(v)$, $f(\lambda u) = \lambda f(u)$ (call these facts (\*)).  We then define a map $\phi : X \to \mathbb{R}$ via $\phi(x) = \|x\| \phi(\frac{x}{\|x\|})$, verify that $\phi|_B = f$, and verify that $\phi \in B^*$.  The latter is not based on directly appealing to the original assumption that $f \in \overline{R(B^*)}$, but on the statement (\*).

Comment: By the way, note that the computation $\|x\| f(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) = f(x)$ is only valid for $x \in B$ (after we have shown that $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$).  It's not valid for $x \in X \setminus B$ because $f(x)$ is not defined in that case.  The purpose of introducing $\phi$ is to extend $f$, in a linear fashion, from $B$ to $X$.

Comment: Ah! okay, so we verify that $f \in R(B^*)$ by checking $R$ hits $f$. The functional in $B^*$ that is carried to $f$ by $R$ is given by $\phi(x) = \|x\| f(x/\|x\|)$.

Comment: I think Royden's treament of this material is somewhat confusing. Rudin does it nicely in his Functional Analysis p.66.

Comment: @Matematleta alas its all confusing with a small mind

Answer (score 1):

The weak$^\ast$ topology on $B^\ast$ is just the subspace topology induced from seeing all linear maps on $X^\ast$ as a subset of the set of all functions from $X^\ast$ to $\Bbb R$. This set of functions has the base as described (an alternative base for this product topology). And $\phi \in B^\ast$ iff any $x \in B$ maps into $[-1,1]$, hence that the map $R$ is well-defined. So $R(B^\ast)$ is a subset of $\prod_{x \in B} [-1,1]_x$, where $[-1,1]_x$ is a copy of $[-1,1]$.

The thing to verigy is that the closure of a set of linear functions only contains linear functions, in the product topology. I would personally use nets for that (it's more natural) but his way is also possible.  So $f \in \overline{R(B^\ast)}$ must imply that $f$ is linear on $B$ and so in $B^\ast$.